# Why does creating a key called "constructor" seem to change the behavior of "this"?

Tags: javascript

Why does creating a key called "constructor" seem to change the behavior of "this"? Take this code for example:

```
var O = {
  constructor: function f1(){},
  k2: function f2(){return this;}
};

console.log(O.k2());//logs "f1"
```

One would assume that "this" would be 'Object' since it's within an object literal, but if I use the name "constructor" as a key suddenly the function inside it becomes "this".  If I try this out I get 'Object':

```
var O = {
  k1: function f1(){},
  k2: function f2(){return this;}
};

console.log(O.k2());//logs "Object"
```

Does the key name "constructor" have special behaviors like _ _ proto _ _ and prototype?  I honestly can't see why "this" attaches to the function f1 here.

Comment: This is a normal behaviour. From [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor): *"Returns a reference to the Object function that created the instance's prototype. Note that the value of this property is a reference to the function itself, not a string containing the function's name."*.

Comment: I get it, so it overrode a constructor property that was already there (the one that guides what "this" refers to).  That's what it seems.  Thanks.  I'll look more into this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `constructor` is the function that created the prototype. [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor).